# Hibernate 6 perfroms update query after select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I wrote a simple entity named "User" and another one called "Company". User entity has company inside with @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY) mapping. When I create the session object and call get() method Hibernate executes select query and after it update, why?

User entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Embedded
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Role role;

    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String info;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Company company;
}
```

Company entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Main:

```
public class HibernateEntityMappingRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
             Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()
        ) {
            session.beginTransaction();

            User2 user2 = session.get(User2.class, 2);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate console log:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.company_id,
        u1_0.info,
        u1_0.birth_date,
        u1_0.firstname,
        u1_0.lastname,
        u1_0.role,
        u1_0.username 
    from
        users u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        users 
    set
        company_id=?,
        info=?,
        birth_date=?,
        firstname=?,
        lastname=?,
        role=?,
        username=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://hibernate.org/community/contribute/intellij-idea/#debugging for details. The problem is that some of your `toString()` implementations (which the IntelliJ debugger invokes) access state of uninitialized entity/collection proxies, which will cause lazy initialization and hence a select query. If you have pending flushes (insert/update/delete) which affect one of the tables that are about to be selected from, Hibernate forcefully executes pending flushes.

By changing your `toString()` implementations or changing how IntelliJ shows objects in the debugger, you can avoid this.

Comment: Thank you, Christian, you made it 100% clear for me